# Redirect after session or token timeout in identity server openid connect

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have asp.net core and identity server as openid connect server.
I want to redirect to a different page rather than the authority url when the token/session is expired due to inactivity. Is there an easy way to do this using configuration or any other way this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

The magic of redirect is done by the [challenge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#challenge) which is set to use `oidc` scheme. Its set by adding `DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc"` on `startup`. To be able to do it in a custom way you need to add a custom challenge which is not as easy as setting some configs. 
Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhttpcontextextensions.challengeasync?view=aspnetcore-3.1)